# Improper Integral on $p$ values

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I want to find $p$ so that the integral converges.

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^p(x^2-1)}dx$$

I know when $p=0$, the integral is divergent.
I already tried for several values of $p$, like $p=1, p=2, p=-1$. As a result, the integral diverges.

In my opinion, there are no values of $p$ such that the integral converges.
But how can I prove it? Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful:$(1)^2 -1 = 0$

Comment: @DonAntonio No.. If $p=0$ the function is $\frac{1}{x^2-1}$, and the integral is not arctan (x). I am sure if $p=0$, the integral is divergent.

Comment: @Niccolo Of course you're right. Before my answer I was trying some ideas and somehoo I left $\;x^2+1\;$ in the denominator. Thanks, I shall delete my past comment.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways to prove this I think. One way, note that I flipped the sign $(x^2-1) \to (1-x^2)$ (if one converged, the other would as well):

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^p(1-x^2)} \ge \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{2} \ln \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\bigg |_{x=0}^{x=1} \to \infty.  $$

Comment: The inequality depends in $\;p\;$, too. It isn't written that it must be positive or whatever...